# Is it possible to use google server side experiments without google analytics

Tags: server-side, google-experiments

Is it possible for us to create a google analytics account, not include its js in the page, but instead try to run server side experiments using google management API.

Basically I am trying to just use the experiment API and push the experiment and their variations and the variations which were chosen so that appropriate analysis/graphs could be created without using the analytics js on the front end.